# R expression variable list

Tags: r, variables, expression

Is it possible to get a vector or list of variables in an expression?

For instance:

```
e <- expression(2 * x^2 + y)
```

The desired output:

```
('x', 'y')
```

Is it possible? Or is it necessary to input variable names manually?

Comment: You'd be slightly better off creating the simpler call object here: `e <- quote(2 * x^2 + y)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `all.vars`:

```
all.vars(e)
[1] "x" "y"
```

Comment: And in case you want to write variations, http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html#walking-the-call-tree-with-recursive-functions describes how to do it with recursive R code.